# Quitting a PhD program for another PhD in Business

Tags: phd, united-states, transfer-student, business-school

I am currently a Ph.D. student of business at University X. Although my professor is great and well-known in the field, their offer was explodable and I had no time to think about it and wait for my other results (because of my situation and some personal pressure I accepted it), also the rank and placements of the university are not that good, so I was not sure about University X from the first moment. Also, I am not happy in this city at all and it is affecting my performance. I want to know my options, Can I transfer to a better university and city? or Should I drop this program and reapply? Do I have to pay back my tuition (I know that I do not have to pay back my stipend) if I quit this program?
Also, I am kind of worry about the reaction of my professor and the university. I deeply appreeciate it if you help me.

Answer (score 3):

**Regarding a PhD:**
Generally speaking, it is common for people to realize that the chosen PhD is not the right one for them after they worked on it for a while.
You should reflect and be sure about why you want to change your PhD.
It could be a phase; any PhD will test your endurance and persistence to finish it. A lot of my co-PhDs were really frustrated during the PhD and some wanted to quit. Some didn't and were happy that they hadn't. Some others did and were happy with their decision too.
I only know one person who quit their PhD and started another one at another Uni. However, that person didn't finish the second either and dropped out in the end.

**Regarding Uni and Ranking:**
Ranking/Prestigiousness is not everything. Your supervisor is more important. I did my PhD in a field, where the world-leading scientist(s) is/are in Belgium. He is far more influential than his counterpart at Harvard/MIT. If you did a PhD under him, you have a guaranteed assistant professorship (or at the very least countless post-doc offers) job afterward.

**Regarding changing:**
Commonly, you cannot take your research and move to another Uni and finish it there. I doubt it is possible, but there might be some odd cases where it was done.
So, I believe that you would need to reapply for a new PhD.

**Regarding Tuition:**
That depends on your founding body/contract, and I advise you to read it yourself and, when in doubt, look for legal advice. Some Unis have student unions that help with that.
FYI: In the Uk, for instance, you don't need to pay anything back.

**Regarding supervisor:**
Talk to him and be honest, that you are not happy, and you want to move somewhere else. They are professionals and won't hold a grudge against you.
Just be sure you pay attention to how you deliver it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and answer. Since The first two years of the program are mostly studying and passing some courses, I have not delved into my research yet, and I am open to changing my research direction toward other university faculty members that have mainly common interests with me.